# JAX-WS webservice client : The server sent HTTP status code 504: Gateway Time-out

Tags: jax-ws, http-status-codes

I am using a JAX-Ws client to invoke a webservice.The webservice runs for a while (say 20-30 minutes).
However after 3-4 minutes I get the following exception on the client side.

The server sent HTTP status code 504: Gateway Time-out:com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 504: Gateway Time-out
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:296)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:245)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:203)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:122)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:626)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:585)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:570)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:467)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:308)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:146)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:129)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.fmer.bsc.test.EdxWebServiceInvokerThread.call(EdxWebServiceInvokerThread.java:57)
    at com.fmer.bsc.test.EdxWebServiceInvokerThread.call(EdxWebServiceInvokerThread.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

I though it could because of client timing out and added the the time out varaibles as below.Still no luck. Also on server I see the webservice is still executing.

```
private static Integer timeOut = new Integer((10 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); //Read as 1O hrs * 60 min * 60 seconds * 1 milli second


//Setting the Request timeout and connection time out 
EdxWebServiceImplService edxWebservice = new EdxWebServiceImplService(WsURL);
edxServicePort = edxWebservice.getEdxWebServiceImplPort();
BindingProvider edxWebserviceBindingProvider  = (BindingProvider)edxServicePort;

//In milli Seconds...
edxWebserviceBindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT,timeout);
edxWebserviceBindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT,timeOut);

//Now invoke the webservice....
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the issues was with the apache httpd webserver which had a default timeout of 120 seconds.

All our webservice calls go through a load balancer (apache httpd server) which then sends to Jboss application server.

so changed the  below property value in httpd.conf file for appache webserver.

```
 Timeout 120
```

To

```
Timeout 18000
```

i.e 5 hours

This change is in addition to the change in JAX-WS client code.